# What is the difference between raw types and generic types in this declaration

Tags: java

What is the difference between raw types and generic types in this declaration

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList();
```

for these  declaration i can't do

```
list1.add("hello");
list2.add("hello");
```

so where is the difference

on other word what is the benefit of the angle brackets in first declaration

Comment: Add a `String` to a `List<Integer>` and wonder why it gives you an error?

Comment: i have update my question .PLZ check it

Comment: @abu_abdelbarr I've addressed your update, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `ArrayList<>(),` the type in angle brackets is inferred from the declaration, so it resolves to `ArrayList<Integer>` at compile time.

If you omit angle brackets, then the assignment uses raw type, i.e. collection type without any information of the element type. No type inference is done by the compiler for this assignment.

Both lines will not compile:

```
list1.add("hello")
list2.add("hello")
```

because both `list1` and `list2` variables are declared as `ArrayList<String>`.

The point of specifying `<>` is that the assignment of `ArrayList()` to `ArrayList<String>` should generate a compiler warning of unchecked assignment, because the compiler can't verify that the raw typed collection to the right of the `=` sign contains only `Integer`s. In a simple case such as yours, you can control the correctness of the code visually. But consider a more complex scenario:

```
ArrayList rawList = new ArrayList();
rawList.add("one");

ArrayList<Integer> list = rawList;
```

Here you break the generic system by assigning a raw list that contains a `String` to a typed list variable that should contain only `Integer`s. That's where the compiler warning of unchecked assignment comes in handy.